# Getting told to place ; in my method

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CoinCounter {

  public static void main(String[] args) { 

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the number of toonies: ");
    int t = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter the number of loonies: "); 
    int l = keyboard.nextInt(); 

    System.out.print("Enter the number of quarters: "); 
    int q = keyboard.nextInt(); 

    System.out.print("Enter the number of dimes: "); 
    int d = keyboard.nextInt(); 

    System.out.print("Enter the number of nickels: "); 
    int n = keyboard.nextInt();   

    int coinCounter = total(t,l,q,d,n);
    System.out.println("The total value of the coins is " + coinCounter + " cents"); 
    finalMessage; 

    static int total(int t , int l , int q , int d , int n) {
      return t*200 + l*100 + q*25 + d*10 + n*5;  
    }//total of coins 

    static String finalMessage( ); {
       System.out.print("Cole Coin Counter Company, 2014"); 
    }//final message

  }//main


}//coinCounter
```

Comment: What's the error message and what exactly about it don't you understand? (I can see the error in your code, but really, you should try to interpret error messages or you won't get very far.)

Comment: Hi Cole, welcome to SO.

Comment: the error comes from the final message saying "VariableDeclarators" also there also seems to be errors in " public static int total(int t , int l , int q , int d , int n) " saying that i should have no brackets and ; instead of commas, whats going on here?

Comment: It appears the closing brace for `main` is placed too late. I believe the closing brace should be before `static int total(...)`.

Comment: ^this guy's a life saver^ i knew i was doing everything right as coding wise it had to be a stupid little bracket. thanks so much for all your help. you dont know how long ive been fighting with it

Answer (score 4):

The problem looks like it's here:

```
finalMessage;
```

That should be

```
finalMessage();
```

Also, you've got a method nested in a method - bad news. `finalMessage()` should not be inside `main()`.

Comment: Might wanna look six lines below that too...

Comment: I didn't notice either of those until you pointed them out. So, basic syntax errors...

Comment: @NathanielFord - yep but I think you've answered the actual "question" (or at least what the title is referring to ;))

Answer (score 2):

```
static String finalMessage( ); {
```

This will produce a syntax error, because of the `;` after your `()`. Simply elide it, like so:

```
static String finalMessage() {
```

As Steve points out, when you call a method, you must use parentheses, like so:

```
finalMessage();
```

Further, as Steve also points out, the definition of a method must be outside all other methods.